# How do we calculate the expected value of $Y$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, variance

Let $\Omega = \{−1, 0, 1, 3\}$ with the probability function $p$ given by

[image]

I want to calculate the expected value and the variance of $X(\omega)=\omega$, $Y(\omega)=5\omega-3$, $Z(\omega)=(\omega-1)^2$.

For $X$ I have done the following :

We have that $X\in \{-1,0,1,3\}$.

The expected value is \begin{equation*}E[X]=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}xP[X=x]=(-1)\cdot \frac{1}{10}+0\cdot \frac{3}{10}+1\cdot \frac{2}{10}+3\cdot \frac{4}{10}= \frac{13}{10}\end{equation*}
The variance is \begin{align*}Var[X]&=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}(x-E[X])P[X=x]\\ & =\left (-1-\frac{13}{10}\right )\cdot \frac{1}{10}+\left (0-\frac{13}{10}\right )\cdot \frac{3}{10}+\left (1-\frac{13}{10}\right )\cdot \frac{2}{10}+\left (3-\frac{13}{10}\right )\cdot \frac{4}{10}\\ & =0\end{align*}

Doe $Y$ we have $Y=5\omega-3\in \{-8,-3,2,12\}$, or not? But then we don't knowthe probabilities.

Or do weuse the property $E[aX+b]=aE[X]+b$ ?

Comment: If you want to be careful, then $X \in \{ -1,0,1,3\}$ should be $X(\omega) \in \{ -1,0,1,3\}$ for all $\omega \in \Omega,$ since $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function. But that's too cumbersome to keep writing out in practice.

Comment: $Y$ is a function of $X(\omega)=\omega$, so you must use the property that you type.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of $E[X]$ is correct but the calculation of $\text{Var}[X]$ is not correct.

$ \text {Var}[X] = \sum(x - E[X])^2 \cdot P(X = x)$ which translates to,

$ \text {Var}[X] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 $

Now, $E[X^2] = (-1)^2 \cdot \dfrac{1}{10} + 1^2 \cdot \dfrac{2}{10} + 3^2 \cdot \dfrac{4}{10} = \dfrac{39}{10}$

So, $ \displaystyle \text {Var}[X] = \frac{39}{10} - \left(\frac{13}{10}\right)^2 = \frac{221}{100}$

Yes you can use the formula $~E[aX+b] = aE[X] + b$

Also note that $~ \text{Var} [aX+b] = a^2 \text{Var}[X]$

Comment: I got it!! As for the covariance of $X$ and $Z$ I have : \begin{align*}\text{Cov}(Z,X)&=E[XZ]-E[X]E[Z]=E[X(X-1)^2]-E[X]E[(X-1)^2]\\ & =E[X(X^2-2X+1)]-E[X]E[(X^2-2X+1)] =E[X^3-2X^2+X]-E[X]E[X^2-2X+1]\\ & =E[X^3]-2E[X^2]+E[X]-E[X]\left (E[X^2]-2E[X]+1\right )\\ & =E[X^3]-2E[X^2]+E[X]-E[X]E[X^2]+2(E[X])^2-E[X]\\ & =E[X^3]-2E[X^2]-E[X]E[X^2]+2(E[X])^2\end{align*}  How can we continue?

Comment: Cov($Z, X$) = COV($X^2 - 2X+1, X$) = COV($X^2 - 2X, X$) = COV($X^2,X$) $- 2 $ COV($X,X$)

Comment: COV($X^2, X$) = $E[X^3] - E[X^2] \cdot E[X]$ and COV($X, X$) = Var{$X$). You already know $E[X^2]$ and $E[X]$ from previous work. You also know Var($X$). All you need to find is $E[X^3]$ which is similar to how I found $E[X^2]$

Comment: Ah ok! The covariance can be negative, right? Thenthe correlation cofficient is \begin{align*}\rho (Z,X)&=\frac{\text{Cov}(Z,X)}{\text{Std}(Z)\cdot \text{Std}(X)}=\frac{\text{Cov}(Z,X)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(Z)}\cdot\sqrt{ \text{Var}(X)}}=\frac{-\frac{579}{100}}{\sqrt{\frac{301}{100}}\cdot\sqrt{ \frac{221}{100}}}=\frac{-\frac{579}{100}}{\frac{\sqrt{301\cdot 221}}{100}}\\ &=\frac{-579}{\sqrt{301\cdot 221}}=\frac{-579}{\sqrt{301\cdot 221}} \approx -2.245\end{align*} Or must it be between $-1$ and $1$ ?

Comment: Of course covariance can be negative but in this case I get covariance as $141/100$. What did you get for $E[X^3]$?

Comment: I have $$E[X^3]=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}x^3P[X=x]=(-1)^3\cdot \frac{1}{10}+0^3\cdot \frac{3}{10}+1^3\cdot \frac{2}{10}+3^3\cdot \frac{4}{10}=- \frac{1}{10}+ \frac{2}{10}+9\cdot \frac{4}{10}=\frac{37}{10}$$ Where is my mistake?

Comment: Great! Now I get the same result as you!! Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula $$\mathbb{E}[aX+b] = a\mathbb{E}[X]+b$$ to see that

$$\mathbb{E}[Y] = 5\cdot \frac{13}{10} -3 = \frac{7}{2}\ .$$

However, you can also calculate it directly because you do have the probabilities for $Y$. For example

$$\Pr(Y=-8) = \Pr(5\omega-3 = -8) = \Pr(\omega=-1)\ .$$

Since $Y$ is defined in terms of $\omega$, its distribution is also determined by the distribution for $\omega$. So once you get the distributions for $Y$ and $Z$ you can calculate their expectations and variances just like you did for $X$.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)